# Oracle/sqlplus: avoid to print header when running a query

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I am running a simple query via sqlplus; and I get a ton of headers for each query.

Is there a way to run the query and get only the result, without get also the header for each record?

Example: `select * from table1;`

this return

```
Name      type          Date          ID       Result
------- ------------   -----------   -----  -----------
data1     data2          data3        data4    data5
```

while I would like to retrieve only the data, without the header, for each record returned.

Is there a way to do so? Since I am saving the output to process it at later time, I would rather have a list of data, without have to process the output and remove the header all the time.

Answer (score 0):

```
SET HEA[DING] {OFF|ON}
   print column headings
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found a way, although this suppress ALL the headers, including the one for the first set of data:

at the prompt you need to set pagesize to 0; this will result in each record entry printed with an empty line to separate them, and without headers.

```
SQL> set pagesize 0
```